# Adding hover function to button causes issues with modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that pulses when it is hovered over, and when clicked brings up a modal box.

my issue is that when the button is clicked, the position of the video being brought up inside the modal is off centre and it flashes. No real idea what's going on, I presume the hover is messing with the content in the modal and applying the hover affects to inside the modal too.

**HTML**

```
<div class="explainerPlay pull-center">
<h1><a href="#videoModal"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#videoModal"></i></a></h1>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="videoModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
```

**JQuery**

```
 /*animate button*/
    $(".explainerPlay").hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated customPulse');
    },function(){

        $(this).removeClass('animated customPulse');
    });
```

Comment: your markup is not correct and JS also has some syntax error.... please check again.

Comment: Could you provide us a JSFiddle of your problem ?

Comment: Looks like your div, `.explainerPlay`, is wrapping your Modal. That could be a possible cause.  Also it appears as though you could use the `toggleClass` method instead of add / remove

Comment: Fixing the divs and changing to toggleClass seems to have fixed it for now. Some positioning issues but I imagine that's just clutter in the HTML generated by the CMS